# Pass form data to PHP from JSP/struts1.x action

Tags: php, jsp, undefined, struts-1

I am developing login form for 3rd party sign-in (say `login.php`). I am completely new to PHP. I have to preserve data coming to our website from 3rd party, so I stored those data in hidden fields inside PHP and while submitting login form in `login.php`, I am able to get form data in my struts action with

```
request.getParameter("data");
```

And my `login.php` looks like below

```
<form id="externalloginform" name="externalloginform" action="/login.do" method="POST">
<input id="username" type="text" name="userid"/>
<input id="password" type="password" name="password"/>
<input id="data" type="hidden" name="data"/>
</form>
```

If he/she successfully logged in I am fine. But in login failure case I have to redirect to same `login.php` with error message and the preserved form data from action class to `login.php`. I am setting,

```
request.setAttribute("loginerr",loginerr);
request.setAttribute("data",data);
```

I forwarded this action method to a jsp in our portal like below,

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('custom-login-form').submit();">
<form id="custom-login-form" name ="custom-login-form" action="/login.php" method ="post">
<input type="hidden" name="loginerr" value="request.getAttribute("loginerr")" />
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="request.getAttribute("data")" />
</form>
```

While I set form method as `get` in jsp, I can get this hidden fields in `login.php` using,

```
$_GET['loginerr'];
$_GET['data'];
```

but in case of `post` method in JSP I am getting error

> undefined index: loginerr

in `login.php`. I used both,

```
$_POST['loginerr']; & $_REQUEST['loginerr'];
$_POST['data']; & $_REQUEST['data'];
```

Any help? I am seriously sitting a full day to get this done. Please do not down-vote. I searched google a lot and not able to find solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `$_REQUEST` alone http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php
Use `isset()` to check if the index exist, before trying to access it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

```
$data  = isset($_REQUEST['data']) ? $_REQUEST['data'] : null;
$error = isset($_REQUEST['loginerr']) ? $_REQUEST['loginerr'] : null;
```

If `data` wasn't found, it will be null. The same thing goes for `$error`.

If you're using PHP 7.0 or newer, you can use the short hand `??` instead (it's the same thing as the above snippet, just a bit cleaner):

```
$data  = $_REQUEST['data'] ?? null;
$error = $_REQUEST['loginerr'] ?? null;
```

Comment: Thanks!!. What is my understanding is that you want me to check if it is set or not before use it in php, Right? to prevent from undefined error. But my question is why the data is not coming to php from jsp in method "post", but the same is coming in case of "get". The data is explicitly visible in url in case of "get" method, which i want to avoid.

Comment: @user8235599 As far as I can see, your codeshould post the form. However, `value="request.getAttribute("data")"` looks wrong. Don't you need to do something like: `value="<%= request.getAttribute("data") %>"` in JSP to actually echo out the request data? The way you have it now would literally post the strting:`request.getAttribute("data")`

Comment: @user8235599 And yes, you should always check if the keys are set before trying to use them and handle it accordingly.